# Prefill Formfield using Javascript/Jquery and Labels from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, formfield

I'm having difficulties prefilling a form using it's Labels in front of the formfields.

The ID's of my formfiels are randomly generated, so also the for="fieldID" for the labels.

An example:

```
<td>
<label class="required" for="ebc2566ad1c3793b">
name:
<font class="error">*</font>
</label>
<span>
<input id="_ebc2566ad1c3793b" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="ebc2566ad1c3793b" placeholder="" maxlength="30" size="16">
</span>
</td>
```

I'm able to use javascript to fill the fields using the ID from the URL, but not using the identifier "name:" which is between the label.

As I'm also using jQuery in soem scripts I'm also not sure which DOM to use.

Examples are very welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? If you already have jQuery imported on the page I would say stick to that because it would be easiest. Also, what is an example URL that you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem 100%, you want to access form labels based on its content yes? If so:

Using the `:contains()` selector you can grab the form labels like this:

```
var nameLabel = $("label:contains('name:')");
```

From there you could use the `.next()` method to grab the sibling element which in this case will be the `span` containing the input field. So to access the input you would do something like this:

```
var nameInput = nameLabel.next().find('input');
```

From there use `.val()` to set its content like so:

```
nameInput.val('John doe')
```

Comment: OK this sounds quite clear, what I do now is:

[code]
<script type="text/javascript">
var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
    var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
    document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
}
</script>
[/code]

I cannot get the code formatted in tis reply :( sorry for that.

Comment: I suggest creating a jsfiddle/plunker where you easiet can illustrate your problem!

Comment: I fixed it with your example, I added it to my existing script, works perfectly and is very clear.